# What are the common fonts used in music?

Tags: font-identification

I'm looking for the typical fonts appearing in classical music scores, like the ones here:

[image]

where you can see some **Allegretto**, and also a *leggiero*, some numbers too, and *m****f***.

And also, what fonts are those used in software like Sibelius, Encore... that looks like *Real Book*'s handwritten font?

[image]

Comment: The hand-drawn lettering on the bottom music sheet looks to be actually hand written and not a font as you can see that letters that appear more than once don't match up, like 'O', 'E' and 'N'.

Comment: @SaturnsEye its possible to have a font that changes the ligature as you type so that it would cycle trough different variations of letters making it seem more natural.

Comment: @joojaa oh right, I've never heard of letters cycling before. News to me! :)

Comment: @joojaa ;) In fact I asked about that [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151967/36389). I don't know if that example is handwritten or not, but I know that font exists in music sheet editors, and it wouldn't be very difficult for me to find that one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the more popular music notation software programs is [Finale](https://www.finalemusic.com/) (at least that was the case when I was in high school). Finale is bundled with a [bunch of fonts](http://www.finalemusic.com/UserManuals/Finale2014Mac/Content/Finale/Alternative_music_fonts.htm) that you'll recognize if you use sheet music with any kind of regularity:

- Broadway Copyist Font
- Engraver Font
- Finale Alpha Notes Font
- Finale Copyist Text Font
- Finale Lyrics Font
- Finale Mallets Font
- Finale Numerics Font
- Finale Percussion Font
- Jazz Font
- Maestro Font

These cover pretty much all musical notation you could ask for. For lettering specifically, look to these:

Finale Copyist Text
[image]

JazzText
[image]

Broadway Copyist Text
[image]

MaestroTimes
[image]

Not sure if these exact fonts are available for licensing outside of the software.

#### Reference:

[Finale Character Sets](https://www.finalemusic.com/UserManuals/Finale2014Mac/Content/Finale/Character_sets.htm)

[Finale Alternative Music Fonts](http://www.finalemusic.com/UserManuals/Finale2014Mac/Content/Finale/Alternative_music_fonts.htm)

Answer (score 11):

I believe that the "Allegretto" is a bold [Times New Roman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_New_Roman).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Steinberg](https://www.smufl.org/fonts/) has made available a number of very complete, [SMuFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MusicXML)-compatible music sheet fonts, of which [***Bravura***](https://github.com/steinbergmedia/bravura) (in OTF, SVG, WOFF & EOT format)

[image: Bravura]

and [***Petaluma***](https://www.steinberg.net/en/products/steinberg_trial_versions/dorico.html) (1350 glyphs)

[image: Petaluma]

are freely available under [the SIL Open Font License](http://scripts.sil.org/ofl).

Answer (score 0):

It's not difficult to find some "jazz fonts" in the internet:

Sibelius software uses *Jazz Inkpen*:

[image]

Also: [JazzFont.com](http://www.jazzfont.com/).

Comment: [Be kind, show a preview of the font please.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font)

Answer (score 0):

The handwritten example uses a number of fonts:

The violin clef: RussMusic (see https://elbsound.studio/music-font-comparison.php?font=RussMusic )

The time signature: probably a text font, could be AshAlpha (from the AshMusic font, same publisher as RussMusic)

The rests look like from a NorFont (RealScore, BopMusic, etc.), see https://www.facebook.com/norfonts .

The chords and the song title is probably handwritten, too many deviations between similar characters.
An overview of handwritten text fonts for this jazz style can be found here: https://elbsound.studio/text-fonts-free-download.php#handwritten

It's possible to create this look in Finale. Examples are available here:
https://elbsound.studio/realbook-look.php#examples

Answer (score 0):

Simplified Arabic Fixed, this is common in typed simplified sheet music.